# How to use x11docker on centos?

Tags: centos7

I want to use x11docker on centos7.But it seems that it would use some commands like 'systemctl --user',and then report message like 'failed to connect to dbus no such file or directory'.Is there any solution?

Comment: Maybe use [ssh](https://ssh.org/) as `ssh -X`. But please give more code (shell commands) as some [mre] in your question.

Comment: The problem is I can't success to use command 'x11docker --desktop x11docker/xfce' to start desktop mode or other to run an apllication.While I used the xclock to check 'ssh -X' is not the probem.

Comment: I recommend to open a ticket at github: https://github.com/mviereck/x11docker